# Discord.NET Case insensitive commands

Tags: c#, command, discord.net

I'm trying to have a bot where it replies with a dad joke where if someone says "I'm ____" it will reply "Hi ____, I'm ____" but the command prefix is case sensitive and if I try to add the other case to the command prefix list, it ignores the other case. Is there any way to ignore the case for command prefixes at all?

Comment: which version of discord.net are you running/

Comment: Version 0.9.6 (Discord.NET + Discord.NET Commands)

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you use `.ToLower()` on the message so you don't have to worry about cases?

I have not used 0.9.6 in a while, so please excuse the lack of code.